# "Now let's..." vs "Let's now..." -- what is the proper sequence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

**Let's now** take a look at the birds in the cage.

**Now let's** take a look at the birds in the cage.

Which of these two sentences is correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think either is improper, the broader context may suggest one is more natural, but syntax can be a very personal thing.

I would only use the first in the following:

“Given that previous results show that free range birds had very few infections, **let's now** take a look at the birds in the cage.”

I would use either in the following:

“We have just finished looking at the free range birds, **now let's (let's now)** take a look at the birds in the cage.”